Logic level translator not working
I’m trying to use an NExperia LSF0204 “4-bit bidirectional multi-voltage level translator” to shift some voltages from 3.3V logic to 5V (or higher, if possible). My understanding of the chip’s functionality was that input logic signals on Side A (inputs/outputs A1 to A4) referenced to reference voltage A, VrefA, are translated to/from Side B (B1 to B4), referenced to VrefB.
So, for example, I was expecting that if I set VrefA to 3.3V, and VrefB to 5V, then a 3.3V logic high input on A1 would appear as a 5V logic high output on B1. This, however, is not what I am seeing.
I am supplying A1, VrefA and VrefB from benchtop supplies. B1 is observed using a multimeter or an oscilloscope. A2 is floating, B2 is connected to the gate of a MOSFET (not shown below). A3, A4, B3 and B4 are all connected to ground, as I was not planning to use them for anything.

Here are the voltages I measure:



VrefA(V)
VrefB(V)
A1(V)
B1(V)




3.3
5.0
3.3
3.1


1.8
3.3
1.8
1.7


5.0
3.3
3.3
2.3



As you can see, B1 always ends up being the same/close to VrefA/A1, it’s not being shifted up to VrefB even a little bit. I even tried swapping VrefA and B around, in case I’d got them the wrong way round.
Have I fundamentally misunderstood how the chip works, or made some obvious error with the circuit?

See https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/3047931.pdf page 9, a pull up or pull down resistor may be needed. Look Fig. 7

The Nexperia data sheet does not provide good application information.
The TI data sheet has some good information about implementation. It indicates that pull-up resistors may be required (are required under open-drain operation.
It looks like all you need is some pull-ups on the B-side.
I did not find information on unused channels. I would probably ground the A side and leave the B-side open or pulled high  through a resistor.


The IC is a simple FET pass gate.
If there is nothing to pull to 5V externally, the IC cannot internally pull a node to 5V.

Thanks everyone, a pull-up resistor was indeed needed. I used 10k between B1/B2 and VRefB which seemed to work fine. Regarding the unused channels - I have A3, A4, B3 and B4 all tied to ground and this didn't seem to affect the behavior of A1/A2 and B1/B2.
